# Migrating WCF Services to ASP.NET Web API - reuse ServiceAuthorizationManager?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, asp.net-web-api, wcf-web-api

I am migrating some WCF services to Web API. Is is possible to reuse the ServiceAuthorizationManager or is it strictly for WCF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `ServiceauthorizationManager` is member of `System.ServiceModel` namespace, it's a concept of WCF.

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceauthorizationmanager.aspx),

> The ServiceAuthorizationManager is part of the WCF Identity Model
>   infrastructure. The Identity Model enables you to create custom
>   authorization policies and custom authorization schemes. For more
>   information about how the Identity Model works, see Claims and
>   Authorization.

Web API assumes that authentication happens in the host (IIS), which uses HTTP modules for authentication. Custom Authorization  is achieved via custom Authorization Filters ( AuthorizeAttribute, AuthorizationFilterAttribute or IAuthorizationFilter). Take a look at [asp.net web Api Security](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api) on asp.net